# Package installed with Conda, but ModuleNotFoundError

Tags: python, conda

I installed my own python package locally with

```
(base) > python -m pip install dbtest/dist/dbtest-1.1.tar.gz
```

where python is is in `~/AppData/Local/Continuum/anaconda3/` (I'm on Windows, and using the base conda environment for simplicity).

The installation is successful and I can see my package is installed:

```
(base) > conda list | grep dbtest
dbtest    1.1    pypi_0  pypi
```

But when I try to import it, it can't be found

```
(base) > python -c "import dbtest"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>, line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'dbtest'
```

I have re-run `conda init` and restarted my shell, but still it can't be found. I don't understand how the conda environment can list it as installed but then not be able to import it under the most austere conditions.

### setup.py for dbtest

```py
from setuptools import setup, find_packages
setup(
    name='dbtest',
    version='1.1',
    packages=find_packages(),
)
```

The project directory goes something like

```
dbtest/
  |_ src/
  | |_ __init__.py
  | |_ a_module.py
  | |_ a_script.py
  |_ setup.py
```

Comment: Since it is your own package, it would help to see the `setup.py` and the structure inside `dbtest-1.1.tar.gz`